# What kind of Bitcoin questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

Given that [a question was recently tagged with the Bitcoin tag,](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) what kind of Bitcoin questions should we accept or encourage?

There is already another site called "[bitcoin.stackexchange.com](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com)", but as of right now it is in Beta so it's not possible to migrate questions to that site.

Finally would our ideas of whats acceptable and not acceptable change once Bitcoin.SE graduates from Beta status?

Comment: it is possible to migrate to that site - as long as a mod does it :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop to be fair, all migrations are still mod-only...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin questions are on-topic if they are about security, especially with a professional bent. The existence of another Stack Exchange site about Bitcoin is not a critical element in making this determination. Similarly, questions about security of computer networks are on-topic here regardless of the existence of [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), questions about security of algorithms and their implementations are on-topic here regardless of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and so on.

Bitcoin questions are off-topic if there is no or very little security aspect to them. If we determine that a question about Bitcoin is off-topic here, but is otherwise a good Stack Exchange questions, the question can preferably be migrated to [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/).

If a question is firmly on-topic here, it should only be migrated with the asker's consent. If a question has already had good, on-topic answers here, it should not be migrated at all. If a question hasn't had any good answer yet, and either the asker requests or agrees to the migration, or the question is only marginally on-topic to begin with, then it is better to migrate the question. But migrations should not happen just because there is another site where the question is *also* on-topic, only because there is another site that is *significantly more suitable* for the question.

Let's look at [your example question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26570/anonymity-through-paying-by-bitcoin):

- The question was firmly on-topic, being about the anonymity of a protocol.
- It is only marginally on-topic on Bitcoin.SE, since it is about comparing a protocol using Bitcoin and protocols not using Bitcoin.
- The asker had a Bitcoin.SE account, but chose to post here instead.
- There was already a reasonable-looking on-site answer (by someone who had no Bitcoin.SE account).

All signs agree: this question should not have been migrated.